# how to insert checkbox before div's innerText

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to dynamically create a check box inside a div using javascript.Here is a part of my code

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('id', 'chkFilm_1');
input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
input.setAttribute('name', 'four');
input.setAttribute('style', 'margin-left:2px;');

var divFilm = document.createElement('div');
divFilm.className = "ChekMarkWrap";   
divFilm.appendChild(input);
divFilm.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
divFilm.innerText = "film";
```

What i'm trying to achieve is inserting the check box before the div's innerText.But the text always comes after the div innerText.

Comment: Have you tried divFilm.prependChild(input);?

Comment: `divFilm.innerHTML += "film";` should work

Comment: @Tdelang u mean $(divFilm).prepend(input), ya i tried its not working

Comment: @MichaelKunst dat did the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your problem could be the line:

```
divFilm.innerText = "film";
```

which would replace the divFilm text instead of appending to it.

The following code seems to work

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('id', 'chkFilm_1');
input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
input.setAttribute('name', 'four');
input.setAttribute('style', 'margin-left:2px;');

var divFilm = document.getElementById("film")

divFilm.appendChild(input)
divFilm.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
divFilm.innerHTML += 'film';
```

This adds these elements to a div in your html with id "film".

This is working in the following link http://jsfiddle.net/yeQeC/

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
divFilm.innerHTML =  divFilm.innerHTML + input.outerHTML+"film" ;
```

or even shorter:

```
divFilm.innerHTML +=  input.outerHTML+"film" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try appending checkbox after appending div , Try this:

```
divFilm.parentNode.insertBefore(input, divFilm);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
divFilm.insertBefore(input, divFilm.childNodes[0]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QgAt3/